SharePoint default form json - How to set a section name to = the display name of a user from a people-picker
I am building a SharePoint default form for creating a new doc set in a SharePoint online Library.  This form has 3 Approver fields (people pickers).
When they go into the submitted form to provide their Approval response, I want each Approval section in the form to read something like "Approval Section for Approver 1 Display name".
I was trying something like this as a part of the body's json:
        "displayname": "[Approver2.DisplayName]",
        "fields": [.....

But I guess I just don't know how to reference that in json.  I would user PowerApps for this form, but the added complication of having the form create a doc set was too challenging.
Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint Online JSON form formatting.
displayname in custom body sections only allows plain "text" values. It does not allow expressions. Even if you add any expression, it will be shown as text only, like:

Documentation: Configure SharePoint list form custom body with one or more sections
